# Start the front-end template : error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: substrate-front-end

OS : centos stream 9
Rust : 1.61
substrate : 2022-05  3.0
polkdadot : 0.9.20
substrate-front-end : 2022-02
nvm node nodejs : 16.14.0

success : Start the local Substrate node
[image]

when i  Start the front-end template
yarn start  , it show error

```
Failed to compile.

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
asset static/js/bundle.js 46.7 KiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset index.html 2.27 KiB [emitted]
asset asset-manifest.json 277 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 27.2 KiB [cached] 9 modules
modules with errors 156 bytes [errors]
  ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js 39 bytes [built] [1 error]
  ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=8000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10 39 bytes [built] [1 error]
  ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 39 bytes [built] [1 error]
  ./src/index.js 39 bytes [built] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at filename (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:102:23)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:128:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:3:103)
    at _next (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:194)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:97

ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=8000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&reconnect=10
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at filename (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:102:23)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:128:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:3:103)
    at _next (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:194)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:97

ERROR in ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at filename (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:102:23)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:128:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:3:103)
    at _next (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:194)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:97

ERROR in ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at filename (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:102:23)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:128:39
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:3:103)
    at _next (/home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:194)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/lzh/substrate-node-template/substrate-front-end-template/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/cache.js:5:97

webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 4 errors in 1753 ms
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Node 17+ - see [some other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported) with possible solutions.

You can tweak the Webpack config as well to only use xxhash, we actually did that in [the apps UI](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/7056) to work around this issue.